# Oracle linux replacement for tsocks

Tags: oracle-linux, socks

I used to use a program called `tsocks` to route traffic through a SOCKS proxy server.  `tsocks` appears to be discontinued or otherwise unavailable on oracle linux.  Anything else one would suggest I use?

Comment: What is the oracle linux version? Your best bet is to try and compile it

Comment: wikipedia has a list of [SOCKS server and client software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Servers). But: isn't tsocks a library (it's a libc-wrapping preload library not been updated in 20 years, so yeah, it might be pretty useless on modern Linuxes)? Can you illustrate how exactly you're using it? My gut feeling is that you'd probably use this with a tun/tap device or some other network tunnel interface that makes tsocks unnecessary.

Comment: Sadly, voting to close since request for more details on use case, which is necessary for recommendations what to use, remainded unanswered for 2 days.

Comment: OL version is 7.9.  I am using it to send specific traffic through a socks gateway opened through our firewall, to an external client.  That's all I know.  Tried curl and ssh, and couldnt get those to work.